# Nuget, Castle Windsor Client Profile vs Full Profile

Tags: castle-windsor, log4net, nuget

I'm trying to use Castle Windsor with Log4Net facility. I've installed the packages through Nuget.

The requirement for this to work is to use Full profile Castle.LoggingFacility. Nuget referenced the Client Profile version.

How can I force Nuget to install the Full profile version?

Comment: Are you talking about the package or about the project properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem earlier and I think you should check your `packages.config` file. There could be `targetFramework="net40-client"`,

which points `NUGet` to the `packages\Castle.LoggingFacility.3.2.0\lib\net40-client` directory.

Simply change it to `net40` and all's done.

Comment: I've resolved the issue by uninstall, change framework, install. However your soulution seems to be better. I'm only thinking about this project reload - is it really going to help? The way references work is that there is a <Reference> entry in the csproj file - you have to change it to reference another version/directory.

Comment: @kubal5003 I believe `NUGet` checks and modifies the csproj file's references. Actually yes, you don't really need to reload the project, I've just figured out that if you change package.config and save it in VS, the `NUGet` will update your csproj immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but it sounds like the issue with the target framework setting on your project:
for Castle.Windsor to work it has to be set to `.NET Framework 4` rather than to `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`.

You can configure it by opening project properties, tab Application (in Visual studio) or just editing the project file.

If that's about the version of the package after all, then usually using NuGet you can append a flag `install-package Castle.Windsor -version 2.5.3` to specify which one to install, but I couldn't find any options there when it comes to `Castle.LoggingFacility`.